# SQL Server LocalDB no longer allows multiple connections

Tags: c#, sql-server, powerbi, localdb, windows-11

I'm using Windows 11 and I have a SQL Server `LocalDB` database that is accessed by a desktop application and Power BI desktop. It used to work normally but suddenly I started seeing connection issues, as described below. The SQL server has a named instance accessed using SQL Server authentication.

Sequence:

1. Restart the machine, check the instance from the command prompt

   ```
   C:\Users\xxx>sqllocaldb info "Instance"                                                                                   
   Name:                Instance                                                                                              
   Version:             11.0.3000.0                                                                                         
   Shared name:                                                                                                            
   Owner:               Domain\UserName                                                                                          
   Auto-create:      No                                                                                                  
   State:               Stopped                                                                                             
   Last start time: 1/16/2023 10:04:30 AM                                                                               
   Instance pipe name:
   ```
2. Open Power BI Desktop, click Add data and try to add anything in the database, all is good and the connection is fine.
3. Check the instance state from the command prompt: same as above (so I can query the database from Power BI, while the instance state is 'Stopped')! How?.
4. Open the desktop application, the application cannot connect to the database and throws an exception at the Connection.Open method with this error message:

   > A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.

   And the following message is repeated in the Windows Application event log:

```
Windows API call WaitForMultipleObjects returned error code: 575. Windows system error message is: {Application Error}
The application was unable to start correctly (0x%lx). Click OK to close the application.
Reported at line: 3621.
```

5. Try to start the instance from the command prompt:

```
sqllocaldb start "Instance"
Start of LocalDB instance "Instance" failed because of the following error:
Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.
```

6. Restart the machine again. Checking the state of the instance in the command prompt gives the same result as above.
7. Start the application, it starts normally, no connection errors.
8. Check the Instance state:

```
Name:               Instance                                                                                              
Version:            11.0.3000.0                                                                                         
Shared name:                                                                                                            
Owner:              Domain\UserName
Auto-create:        No                                                                                                  
State:              Running                                                                                             
Last start time:    1/17/2023 3:18:49 PM                                                                                
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#28451FA3\tsql\query
```

9. Start Power BI and try to connect to the database, it won’t connect. The following error appears

   > A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.

   And this message comes up in the event viewer

   > Windows API call WaitForMultipleObjects returned error code: 575. Windows system error message is: {Application Error}
   > The application was unable to start correctly (0x%lx). Click OK to close the application.
   > Reported at line: 3621.

I've searching in Google and Microsoft for a couple of days, but I cannot find anyone having the same issue. I suspect a recent update to Windows 11 that caused these issues, as it was running perfectly before.

Both the desktop application and Power BI should be able to access the database simultaneously without issues.

Comment: Check also exec sqlcmd

Comment: Event Viewer: search for if exists erros

Comment: I don't suppose there's an `errorlog` file anywhere like its feature-enabled siblings record?

Comment: Consider nuking your LocalDB instance and starting over, just in case that'll fix it. You don't need to lose your databases since you can just reattach those to the new instance.